# How to configure raspberry to get a static IP without auto assigning a DHCP IP?

Tags: debian, networking, dhcp

I have a raspberry PI in a network where all clients get a DHCP IP address assigned automatically.
DHCP-IPs are "192.168.0.X" with subnet mask "255.255.255.0"

But for my raspberry (and other devices) I want to use a fixed IP address in another network.
Desired IP "192.168.X.Y" with subnet mask "255.255.0.0"

The raspberry should get the IP "192.168.20.104" with subnet mask "255.255.0.0".

My "/etc/network/interfaces" looks like

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.20.104
  netmask 255.255.0.0
  gateway 192.168.0.252
```

This works ok so far, my raspberry gets the address "192.168.20.104", but it also gets a DHCP address assigned (in my case "192.168.0.173").

Output of "sudo ip addr show":

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:37:1d:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.20.104/16 brd 192.168.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.0.173/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe37:1d30/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

But I want the raspberry to use my **static address only**. There should be **no DHCP** address.

Is there an error in my "interfaces" file?
Can someone explain why I get a DHCP address although I configured a static address?

What do I have to change in my config file so that I don't get a DHCP address?

Comment: The netmask for that IP should be 255.255.255.0.

Comment: @schaiba Youre right, /24 would be the correct subnet, but in my case I have to use /16. But /24 would not make a difference to my "problem"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running a `dhcpcd` service that is giving you IP addresses no matter what the configuration you have.

imo you should not even have it installed, as `dhclient` normally does the job. (I am assuming Debian here, maybe I am a bit off) You probably installed it in substitution, so we won't be deinstalling it just in case in the future you define a dhcp enabled interface.

So we will be taking it out of boot configuration, and stopping it.

```
apt-get install chkconfig
chkconfig dhcpcd off
service dhcpcd stop
```

Would you please change /etc/network/interfaces it to:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.20.104
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.255.255
    gateway 192.168.0.252
```

And afterwards do a:

```
sudo service networking restart
```

Comment: I copied your config into my interfaces file and rebooted the raspberry. after booting the static ip works fine, but I again to have a DHCP ip... so there is no difference

Comment: It should not be happening. You must be calling dhclient somewhere else. Can you show me the output of "dpkg -l | grep dhcp"

Comment: and also the output of "ps ax | grep dhclient"

Comment: dpkg -l | grep dhcp:
ii  dhcpcd5                               6.7.1-1+rpi3                              armhf        DHCPv4, IPv6RA and DHCPv6 client with IPv4LL support
ii  isc-dhcp-client                       4.3.1-6                                   armhf        DHCP client for automatically obtaining an IP address
ii  isc-dhcp-common                       4.3.1-6                                   armhf        common files used by all of the isc-dhcp packages

ps ax | grep dhclient:
 1023 pts/3    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto dhclient

Comment: do a "ps ax | grep dhcp" please

Comment: ps ax | grep dhcp:
  724 ?        Ss     0:00 /sbin/dhcpcd
 1178 pts/3    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto dhcp

Comment: exactly as suspected, dhcpcd is running. I will extend my reply.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution where only a modification of the interfaces file is necessary:

Just added the following line at the end of the file:

```
iface default inet dhcp
```